# change div background color on click REACT

Tags: reactjs

The function "toggleselect" works as intended but I also need to change the background color of the division. Any ideas?

```
render: ({id}) => (
          <div id={id} className='button blue' onClick={()=>toggleSelect(id)}>
            <a>
              <div role="button">
                <label>Form: </label><input type='text'></input> <br></br>
        
                <label>Func: </label><input type='text'></input>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        )
```

Comment: Create a state with a different class name then pass it to the className attribute, in your handler use the setState function to change the className state.

Comment: no, the answer's css way is so much easier

Comment: actually, no, KToxcon has a point.

Comment: It might help to clarify what you want: do you want your div to change to blue after it's clicked, and stay that way, or become blue *while you are clicking it?*

Comment: If you want your div to change to blue after it's clicked, KToxcon has pretty much answered it. If you want your button to become blue while you are clicking it, use `:active`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css works, but you also choose to do it more dynamically.

```
const toggleColor = () => {

   //assuming toggleSelect set state for `selected` state
   switch (selected){
       case 'blue': return 'blue'
       case 'red': return 'red' //or whatever #hexColor
       return: 'inherit'
   }

}


render: ({id}) => (
          <div id={id} 
               className='button blue' 
               style={{ color: toggleColor() }}
               onClick={()=>toggleSelect(id)}>
            <a>
              <div role="button">
                <label>Form: </label><input type='text'></input> <br></br>
        
                <label>Func: </label><input type='text'></input>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        )
```

Comment: My solution is pretty similar to this!

Answer (score 1):

Create a state with a different class name then pass it to the className attribute in your element, in your event handler use the setState function to change the class state to another class.

If you're using hooks:

```
const [clickedStyle, setClickedStyle] = React.useState('')//your default class;

//In your element
<div className={clickedStyle} >

//In your event handler
const handleClick = (_event) => {
  //OTHER LOGIC
  setClickedStyle('');//Your other class
}
```

If you're using class components:

```
//Your state
this.state = {
  clickedStyle: ''
}

//Your event handler
function handleClick(_event){
  //Other logic...
  this.setState({ clickedStyle: '' }) //Change your default class
}

//In your element
<div className={this.state.clickedStyle} >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.buttonblue:active {
  color: #0070f3; 
}
```

That is blue, by the way - the common blue that links look like. Play around, any hex or colorname works.

If you need a further explanation, that is CSS, and you are using the `:active` aspect of css, which allows you to set the behavior when something is clicked.

**I'm considering removing this. It doesn't answer your question, I've realized.**